# the "mother frame" disapear after showing the next frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

I am actually working on a java project which shows many frames, and when we click on a button then we go to the appropriate frame ... the problem is that the first frame always stays visible.

I have tried f1.setVisible(false); in the action performed, but the same problem persist.

Comment: Please show us some code. We need to see how you are attempting to do the task in order to tell you what may be wrong.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  BTW - by *"project which shows many frames"*  DYM `JFrame` instances, or frames in web pages,or video, or..?

Comment: Your problem is that you're likely calling `setVisible(false)` on the wrong JFrame instance since if you called this on the actual visualized JFrame, it certainly would disappear. But having said this I heartily endorse @Andrew's and MRI's recommendations (1+ to both of them). Use a CardLayout.

Comment: I'm trying to apply the MVC architecture in eclipse there is too much code to paste in fact there are three classes model, view & controller & in the controller  the treatment of action listener and action performed as shown in the following example: 
class b2listener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      f1.setVisible(false);
      Frame2 f2= new Frame2();
      f2.setVisible(true);
  }
} well you do not have to understand all that I want just a simple example when I click on a button the window mother will be gone and the new window is displayed ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upon opening a new frame, also call a method which closes your window

```
private void closeWindow(){
    WindowEvent event = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: True, upon replacing that code with setVisible, it behaved as intended. Appearantly he flagged this as the solution, so I guess it worked for him somehow. Would be a lot easier to identify the problem if we had some code to look at.

Answer (score 6):

I've suggested this like a thousand times, but instead of multiple frames, have a single frame use an appropriate layout manager (e.g. `CardLayout`) that can toggle multiple views.

For more information, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).